# Ubuntu image does not want to work on UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

Recently, I decided to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 10 installation for a less resource intensive OS and something better for development. I have, however, ran into so many issues.

I downloaded the Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 ISO (amd64) and used Rufus to put it on a USB drive. When I tried to boot it, however, it had issues with SecureBoot, so I turned SecureBoot off. Now, I try again. I get somewhere this time. A very basic GRUB interface comes up asking me if I want to try without installing, install, OEM install, or run a memory test. I have tried selecting both Try and Install, however, nothing but a black screen shows and I never get anywhere.

Finally, I decided to switch the UEFI to the legacy CSM boot. This time, the live Ubuntu launched perfectly fine. I would be ok with this, but I do not want to go through the effort of installing a CSM Ubuntu alongside a UEFI Windows. (from what I have read it is a long, complicated process)

I am wondering if there is a way to use Ubuntu with UEFI and solve my black screen problem. I have tried using both Rufus and Unetbootin, but they do that same thing. Any ideas?

**Update**

using `nomodeset` when using the grub launcher, I can see that things get stuck at a line that looks like: `wmi: Mapper loaded`

Comment: What brand/model system? Do you have Intel Smart Response or virtualization turned in in UEFI?

Comment: An answer to oldfred's question would help us to identify specific hardware issues that has been resolved from others using the same equipment.

Answer (score 1):

First, the black "screen problem" you described isn't actually a problem.  That is a part of the installation process.  You have, as you mentioned, the option to go straight to install, or to actually boot to Ubuntu and use it ("Try Ubuntu without installing it").

Also, for your convenience you can run the install process right from the `Try Ubuntu` environment, which is a fully functioning Ubuntu session, which the availability of all the tools of a full install.  The reason I say all the tools, is because, just as with a full install, you have the main tool `apt-get` with which to install just about anything you want.

Once you're at the `Desktop` in `Try Ubuntu`, you'll have a Desktop icon named `Install Ubuntu`.  You can click on that Icon to start the process.  During the process if you have any questions concerning any of the steps you can easily switch to another Window or browser and research the question.

The install is very seamless.  If you have a specific partition where you want to install Ubuntu, just indicate that partition.  All your other partitions will be untouched.

**Ubuntu does work nicely on UEFI**

You have the option of booting into Ubuntu in either UEFI or Legacy mode.  Ubuntu will recognize the mode and install the mode accordingly.  If you want to be have the option for either Booting Windows 10 (in UEFI mode) or Ubuntu, then you have to use the UEFI mode.  If you won't be using any version of Windows on now or later, it wouldn't matter which mode you select.  All the new Intel based machines have UEFI support.  So the UEFI mode installation will work in all machines from the past 5 years or so.  Older machines might not boot the UEFI operating systems.

The only part of the UEFI machine functionality that isn't currently available is the `Secure Boot`.  Just disable that option.  Windows 10 will still work fine and Ubuntu in UEFI will install and work fine as well.

This answer is addressing your topic **Ubuntu image does not want to work on UEFI**.  I hoped to clarify that it does work nicely with `UEFI`.  The ISO has two boot loaders, one for `UEFI` and one for `Legacy`.

Comment: The problem is, when I choose to try Ubuntu, the screen goes blank.

Comment: Actually I notice you have used the 'nomodeset' option.  Will you an actual copy/paste output of the last few lines up to where the freeze occurs to your question.  Also show your exact `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to burn the Ubuntu ISO file to a DVD, boot the DVD, and try/install Ubuntu that way. And oh, switch back to UEFI boot. You won't have any more trouble. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

In a virtual machine inside Windows, you may try to boot to Ubuntu. Then, access the Startup Disk Creator there. You can try extracting the ISO of Ubuntu to your flash drive using that software. Let us know what you got by then.